# Unable to save existing excel document modified by Openpyxl python3

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to edit an already existing excel document using openpyxl. After editing when I try saving the document it throws an error saying "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'". I am quite sure that it is occurring while saving the document. Following is my code -

```
import openpyxl
db_path = r"C:\\Users\\mahapatr\\Desktop\\Newfolder"
iterationSheetName = 'MyIterationSheet.xlsx'
IterationSheetWorkbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(db_path+r'\\'+iterationSheetName)
IterationSheetSheet = IterationSheetWorkbook.active
print(IterationSheetSheet['F38'].value)
edgeRowNumber = '38'
IterationData = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for cols,values in zip(['G','H','I','J','K','L'],IterationData):
        #d = octaneIterationSheetSheet.cell(row=edgeOctaneRowNumber,column=cols,value=int(values))
        print("Old Value",IterationSheetSheet[cols+edgeRowNumber].value)
        IterationSheetSheet[cols+edgeRowNumber].value = int(values)
        print("New Value",IterationSheetSheet[cols+edgeRowNumber].value)
IterationSheetWorkbook.save(db_path+r'\\'+'sample.xlsx')
IterationSheetWorkbook.close()
```

If anyone can point me to why Am I getting this error it will be of great help and will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must provide a complete traceback of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using openpyxl version 2.6.0. Degrading it to 2.5.10 helped me. There was nothing wrong in the code.